# Selecting values from a random array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the 3 arrays.

```
$a = array([ 'name' => 'Max', 'age' => '21' ])
$b = array([ 'name' => 'Tom', 'age' => '31' ])
$c = array([ 'name' => 'Lucy', 'age' => '41' ])
```

i want to  select a random one , and then access the keys within the array.

So for example:

```
$selectedarray = array($a,$b,$c)
echo $selectedarray['name'];
```

Comment: keys always be `name` and `age`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_rand` to pick a random index from the array of all entries

```
$entries = [
    [ 'name' => 'Max', 'age' => '21' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Tom', 'age' => '31' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Lucy', 'age' => '41' ]
];
$selected = $entries[array_rand($entries, 1)];
var_dump($selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss one step - random picking. You use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) or do it by hand:

```
$array_pool = array($a,$b,$c);
$selected_array = $array_pool[array_rand($array_pool)];
...
```

or

```
$array_pool = array($a,$b,$c);
$selected_array = $array_pool[mt_rand(0, count($array_pool))];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `rand` method.

```
<?php
    $a = [ 'name' => 'Max', 'age' => '21' ];
    $b = [ 'name' => 'Tom', 'age' => '31' ];
    $c = [ 'name' => 'Lucy', 'age' => '41' ];
    $selectedarray = [$a,$b,$c];
    print_r($selectedarray[rand(0,count($selectedarray)-1)]);
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/752158